# Add special characters in csv pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8

While writing strings containing certain special characters, such as

```
    Töölönlahdenkatu
```

using **to_csv** from **pandas**, the result in the csv looks like

```
    T%C3%B6%C3%B6l%C3%B6nlahdenkatu
```

How do we get to write the text of string as it is? This is my to_csv command

```
    df.to_csv(csv_path,index=False,encoding='utf8')
```

I have even tried

```
    df.to_csv(csv_path,index=False,encoding='utf-8')
    df.to_csv(csv_path,index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

and still no success.There are other characters replaced with random symbols

```
    '-' to â€“
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: buddy, noticed the .. in ```convert_str = convert_str..decode("utf-8")```? There should be only one.

Comment: thanks for the answer mate. That was correct. I had error when the content read itself was coming with random characters. Hence was confused. However, the solution you provided works neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is remove German umlauts and Spanish tildes. There is an easy solution for that.

```py
import unicodedata

data = u'Töölönlahdenkatu Adiós Pequeño'
english = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
print(english)
```

output : b'Toolonlahdenkatu Adios Pequeno'

Let me know if it works or if there are any edge cases.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. how would I go about it, if the data is in a variable instead of a string explicitly mentioned? and how can I remove the "b" annotation denoting bytes in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Special characters like `ö` cannot be stored in a csv the same way english letters can. The "random symbols" tell a program like excel to interpret the letters as special characters when you open the file, but special characters cannot be seen when you view the csv in vscode (for instance).